# TexMaker could not start the command /usr/texbin/latex after upgrading TexShop

Tags: texmaker

I am using TexMaker 4.4.1 and have no problem. Today suddenly TexShop said that it should be updated to 3.5.4 and I agreed. After that, I came back to TexMaker and now I have the error as showed in the title.

I reinstalled MacTex, but the issue was not resolved. When I checked in /usr, there is no "texbin" directory (even after reinstalling MacTex).

What should I do to resolve the issue?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html

Comment: Hi Johannes, but I reinstalled MacTex after upgrading to El Capital, but it still does not work.

Comment: did you change the paths in texmaker?

Comment: It's okay now, thank you very much. How can I close the issue?